# Why are there lines on some of my photos?

Tags: film, 35mm, developing, fujifilm, scanning

There are green-ish lines running down some of my images. I got it developed/scanned by a local film store. Film is not expired. Shot on a Canon AE-1 Program. Still learning how to shoot in manual mode so some are underdeveloped. [image]
[image]

Comment: More info would help.  What does "local film store" mean.  Pro lab or   department store that may not have skilled techs. ?  What kind of film ? did you set the aperture and shutter speed to what the  the light meter reading said was needed ? Did you set the ASA to the proper ASA for the film you were using ?  Please give us a very detailed explanation. Have you had prints made to see if they are similar to the scans?

Comment: @AlaskaMan A store in my area that specializes in film processing, they process the film in house every other day. So it's not a cvs/walgreens kind of place that ships out. I used Fujifilm Superia 400 35mm film. I adjusted the shutter and aperture while reading the light meter so I believe I did that correctly, as well as setting the ASA to 400. I have not had prints made, only a CD of the scanned pictures.

Comment: @Hueco Please look at [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to my eye like the negatives may have been significantly underexposed or underdeveloped. This resulted in negatives with very little density (they're almost transparent). Then when the negatives were scanned and reversed to give a positive image the lab applied a lot of gain to try and draw *something* out of the very dark images.

Green tint is a tell-tell sign that color negative film was underexposed, processed as if it were properly exposed (they have no way of knowing it was underexposed until after it is developed unless you tell them *before* they develop it), and then pushed to the absolute limits when printed or scanned. The lines are probably an indication that they did as much as they could within the capability of the scanner being used.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that these are caused by the scanner used by the lab ... and not actually on the film itself.  Is it possible something caused streaking not he film negatives?  I suppose it's possible, but after many decades of shooting film, this isn't something I've experienced (whether sending the film to a lab or developing myself)  But in my years of shooting film, I never had the film scanned.

My suggestion is to pick up a magnifying loupe (search for "Loupes & Magnifiers" as a search term and you'll find most real camera stores or online stores specializing in camera gear will have many choices ... these are very inexpensive.)  You can inspect the film negative using the magnifier to see if you can notice the streaking on the actual film surface.  It is possible to scratch film, but as I inspect your images the lines appear to have color shifting -- they do not appear to be scratches.  This is another reason I suspect these are caused by the digital scanner.

If they are caused by the scanner (not a problem with the physical negatives) then that's good news for you because they can be re-scanned using a different scanner to hopefully get better results.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the negatives when I have a chance. This was the only highly recommended film developing place I could find in San Diego, so may need to start searching for another place.